# Vitess guestbook example not working in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, vitess

I am following the [instructions](http://vitess.io/getting-started/#direct-connection-to-mysqld) on how to setup vitess in kubernetes. I am using minikube 0.15 on my local machine (windows 10) running on virtualbox 5.1.12.

I have managed to get all the way to step 12 before I start seeing strange things happening.

When I run `./vtgate-up.sh` everything starts fine, but the service stays in a pending state.
[image: The service is pending even though all the pods have started] 
At first I didn't think anything of it until I went on to the next step of trying to install the guestbook client app.

After running `./guestbook-up.sh` again everything went fine, no errors, but the service is again in a pending state, and I don't get an external endpoint.
[image: service in pending state, and no external endpoint]

I tried going on to the next step, but when I run `kubectl get service guestbook` I am suppose to get an expernal-ip, but I don't. The instructions say to wait a few minutes, but I have let this run for an hour and still nothing.

[image: no external-ip]

So here is where I am stuck. What do I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that you can't get an external IP in this scenario since that gets created in response to the [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-loadbalancer) service type, which [does not work in Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#known-issues).

For the vtgate service, it actually shouldn't matter since the client (the guestbook app) is inside Kubernetes and can use the cluster IP. For the guestbook, you could try to work around the lack of LoadBalancer support in Minikube to access the frontend from outside the cluster in a couple different ways:

1. Use [kubectl port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_port-forward/) to map a local port to a particular guestbook pod.
2. Or, change the [guestbook service type](https://github.com/youtube/vitess/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/guestbook-service.yaml#L15) to [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport) and access that port on your VM's IP address.